# How can I return the unique number of digits in a character string in R?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a vector of strings with 24 digits each. Each digit represents an hour, and if the digit is "0" then the rate from period 0 applies and if the digit is 1 then the rate from period 1 applies.

As an example consider the two strings below. I would like to return the number of periods in each string. For example:

```
str1 <- "000000000000001122221100"
str2 <- "000000000000000000000000"

#str1: 3
#str2: 1
```

Any recommendations? I've been thinking about how to use str_count from stringr here. Also, I've searched other posts but most of them focus on counting letters in character strings, whereas this is a slight modification because the string contains digits and not letters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option by using `charToRaw`.

```
length(unique(charToRaw(str1)))
[1] 3
length(unique(charToRaw(str2)))
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an ugly solution, but here goes

```
length(unique(unlist(strsplit(str1,split = ""))))
```

Comment: Awesome. Yes I came up with something slightly similar, but I was thinking there had to be something more elegant. Can definitely work with this if nothing else turns up.

Comment: You could do `length(table(strsplit(str1,"")))` to shorten it up a bit